# Selenium ElementNotVisibleException is an instance of InvalidStateException

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to catch an InvalidStateException (and only this exception!) but my code is throwing out an ElementNotVisibleException and it is still being caught. I know that this is the problem because I did this:

```
try{
    thrown new ElementNotVisibleException("why???");
}
catch(InvalidElementStateException e){
    System.out.println("Welp, this sucks.");
}
```

And, welp, this sucks.

Selenium javadocs doesn't list ElementNotVisibleException as a subclass of InvalidElementState Exception, yet Java seems to think that this is the case. Can anyone enlighten me/suggest a workaround? Thanks!

Oh, and I'm using Java 7, Selenium 2.46.

Comment: Ah, I now realize I was looking at outdated javadocs...

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElementNotVisibleException` is a subclass of `InvalidElementStateException`, `ElementNotVisibleException` *is* an `InvalidElementStateException`. This is completely expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Selenium javadocs do list ElementNotVisibleException as a subclass of InvalidElementState and thus as @Andrew already said, the behavior is as expected/designed. -> see [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.html)

I quote:

```
public class ElementNotVisibleException
extends InvalidElementStateException
```